# How to configure Octave terminal to output numbers without scientific notation?

Tags: octave

I am trying to print a long table of numbers in octave terminal.

```
disp(vec);
```

What I get

```
7.0931e-01
6.2041e-05
9.7740e-01
9.9989e-01
8.8428e-01
9.0524e-01
...
```

Such numerical notation is a pain to read. How can I set octave terminal to output numbers normally as `0.7, 0.014, 0.95`?

Comment: Configure the coersion of data type as gnu octave presents matrices to screen using the `format options` features see: https://octave.org/doc/v4.0.1/Terminal-Output.html  `format long g` or `format short g`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `format short g` to display each number is a more logical format

```
format short g
disp(vec)

%     0.70931
%  6.2041e-05
%      0.9774
%     0.99989
%     0.88428
%     0.90524
```

Comment: Also `help format` shows more options. E.g. `format short e` will return it to the default.

Answer (score 1):

Using 'fprintf' could help in such cases

```
a=0.0001234;
fprintf('%.3f\n',a)
```

But here the limitation is that number of decimal points would be fixed so in some numbers it will display zeros at the end while for some numbers it might cut off the number.